# Java Wep Application Deployment

Tags: java, security, tomcat, web, deployment

I wrote my first web app using the Vaadin framework and I'm now trying to deploy it online. I exported it to a .war file and uploaded here: http://www.eatj.com/ But I get an error about security when trying to run. (Project name - JTPWebApp)

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet com.example.jtpwebapp.JtpwebappUI$Servlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
root cause

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission com.example.jtpwebapp.disable-xsrf-protection read)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1285)
    java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:652)
    com.vaadin.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.getSystemProperty(DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.java:148)
    com.vaadin.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.getApplicationOrSystemProperty(DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.java:121)
    com.vaadin.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.checkXsrfProtection(DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.java:260)
    com.vaadin.server.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.<init>(DefaultDeploymentConfiguration.java:80)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.createDeploymentConfiguration(VaadinServlet.java:183)
    com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:95)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:120)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

It works fine offline. I created the file server.policy and client.policy with this code

```
grant  
{  
    permission java.security.AllPermission;  
};
```

but I'm not sure where to place them, after exporting to .war file I don't see them inside.
Sorry if it's something simple, but I'm writing my first web app and I'm stuck right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm strongly recommend you to try deploy your first app to the OpenShift Redhat. It's easy and works without security manager.